# Why UIView.contentScaleFactor is 1 while UIScreen.main.scale is 2 for iPad Pro 11 inch (2nd gen)?

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, uikit

According to [Apple's doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622657-contentscalefactor), UIView's contentScaleFactor property is

> The scale factor determines how content in the view is mapped from the
> logical coordinate space (measured in points) to the device coordinate
> space (measured in pixels). This value is typically either 1.0 or 2.0.

For iPad Pro 11 inch (2nd gen), the logic coordinate space size is (1194.0, 834.0) and device coordinate space is (2388.0, 1668.0). They can be obtained through the `bounds` and `nativeBounds` properties of `UIScreen.main` respectively. So one point corresponds to 2 pixels. This is consistent with the face that the value of UIScreen.main.scale is 2.0.

However, when I print `contentScaleFactor` of the view of my app's home view controller on the same iPad, the output is 1.0.

Why the inconsistency between `UIView.contentScaleFactor` and `UIScreen.main.scale`?